# Java spring combined with a Go web server?

Tags: spring-mvc, go

I am looking at using Go for my web server:

https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/

I was actually going for:

https://spring.io/

since it comes with tons of modules for a web server, like security, data, etc.

Would it make sense to use Go as the Web Server for handling traffic/request and have Spring behind for the actual building of the back-end/MVC?

Or would you typically needs to make a decision between either Go or Spring?

Answer (score 2):

> Would it make sense to use Go as the Web Server for handling traffic/request and have Spring behind for the actual building of the back-end/MVC?

No, I don't think so. It's better to take `nginx` and have Tomcat server with Spring application behind it.

> Or would you typically needs to make a decision between either Go or Spring?

Yes, choose what's better for your current task. You can use Spring for the entire web application, Go for some parts, etc.

Comment: Not sure I understand the last part, you suggest that I use spring for the web application and then Go for the web server?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I mean, that you can use Spring for entire web application and Go for some parts of it. Then, you can reverse traffic from front-end nginx to back-end Spring/Go. For example, Go can deal very well with high concurrency requests processing and with long living connections (WebSockets, long polling requests and so on). But keep in mind, that Java also can do all that things perfectly well. Check Netty and Vert.x frameworks. Also, read about microservice architecture.